# Scala abstract case class

Tags: scala

Given any `Card` I would like to be able to get the next and the previous `Cards` if they exist.

The idea with the `next()` and `prev()` functions is that they returns the next or previous `Suits`, respectively. The order of the suits to be: `Hearts`, `Spades`, `Diamonds`, `Clubs`.

For more clarification, I should do these

```
// case class Card(n : Int, s : Suit)

// 1. define abstract case class Suit

// 2. define abstract case classes RedSuit and BlackSuit

// 3. define concrete case classes Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs

// 5. define abstract methods next():Suit and prev():Suit on Suit class

// 6. implement the next():Suite and prev():Suit on each of the Hearts, Diamonds,Spades and Clubs classes

// 7. implement the next():Card and prev():Card on the Card class
```

But in the first place I can't implement the `next()` on Hearts class

```
case class Card(n: Int, s: Suit)

abstract case class Suit{
   type cardsuit <: Suit
   def next(): cardsuit
   def prev(): cardsuit
}

abstract case class RedSuit extends Suit {
   type red <: RedSuit
}

abstract case class BlackSuit extends Suit {
   type black <: BlackSuit
}

case class Hearts extends RedSuit {
   type red = Hearts
   def next(): Spade = ??? // I wanna have Spades hier 
   def prev(): Club = ??? // I wanna have Clubs hier
}
```

Comment: You should never have abstract case classes.

Comment: Can you explain why case classes inheritance is so bad?

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do… In any case, case classes shouldn't be subclassed by other case classes (the compiler should even warn you about this).

Regarding modeling your suits, how about something like this?

```
trait Suit {
  type ThisSuit <: Suit
  type PrevSuit <: Suit
  type NextSuit <: Suit

  def prev: PrevSuit
  def next: NextSuit
}

trait RedSuit extends Suit {
  type ThisSuit <: RedSuit
}
trait BlackSuit extends Suit {
  type ThisSuit <: BlackSuit
}

case object Hearts extends RedSuit {
  type ThisSuit = Hearts.type
  type PrevSuit = Nothing
  type NextSuit = Spades.type
  def prev = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def next = Spades
}
case object Spades extends BlackSuit {
  type ThisSuit = Spades.type
  type PrevSuit = Hearts.type
  type NextSuit = Diamonds.type
  def prev = Hearts
  def next = Diamonds
}
case object Diamonds extends RedSuit {
  type ThisSuit = Diamonds.type
  type PrevSuit = Spades.type
  type NextSuit = Clubs.type
  def prev = Spades
  def next = Clubs
}
case object Clubs extends BlackSuit {
  type ThisSuit = Clubs.type
  type PrevSuit = Diamonds.type
  type NextSuit = Nothing
  def prev = Diamonds
  def next = throw new NoSuchElementException
}
```

You may want `prev` and `next` to return `Option[PrevSuit]` and `Option[NextSuit]`, respectively, rather than throwing exceptions; or make the suits wrap around between Hearts and Clubs.

Comment: It gives an error ( type mismatch In Hearts case)        
found: Spades.type (with underlying type object Spades)         
 required: Hearts.PrevSuit             
    def next= Spades

Comment: @Saar - Use `:paste` before pasting into the REPL, since there are circular dependencies between classes.